# can't get values from items on dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

I have this in my page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="membros" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and in the code behind, I have this:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            members.Items.Clear();
            members.Items.Add(new ListItem("Choose...", ""));

            foreach (DataRow item in com.Execute("select * from tableMembers").Rows)
            {
                 members.Items.Add(new ListItem(item["name"].ToString(), item["id_user"].ToString()));
                 contForeach++;
            }
        }
```

and when I try to get the value from SelectedIndex I can't because he always get me 0 independently of what index I choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put that in `if(!IsPostBack)` so that it can load the dropdown at first time the form loads,right now it is loading everytime the page loads so your missing your selection.

```
      if(!IsPostBack)
      {
        members.Items.Clear();
        members.Items.Add(new ListItem("Choose...", ""));

        foreach (DataRow item in com.Execute("select * from tableMembers").Rows)
        {
             members.Items.Add(new ListItem(item["name"].ToString(),           item["id_user"].ToString()));
             contForeach++;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the `IsPostBack` mentioned, you should be doing it this way instead of looping through the data

Modify your markup

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="membros" runat="server" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="user_id">
```

From code behind, bind the data

```
  if(!IsPostBack)
  {

     DataTable dt = com.Execute("select * from tableMembers");
     members.DataSource = dt;
     members.DataBind();

     members.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Choose...", ""));

 }
```

Bound controls like DropdownList, GridView, DataList etc have `DataSource` property that you can use to assign a collection to them and they would loop through it and extract the data.